# Replace words of length exactly equal to 'n' using preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

I have a string -

```
 $file_data = This is a sample text. This text will be used as a dummy text for various RegEx operations using PHP.
```

I want to replace every 4 letter word with `*`

The Regex I'm using is

```
preg_replace("/\w{4}/", "*", $file_data)
```

But this also replaces words with length >=4. I want it to be strictly 4. How should I do it?

Comment: Maybe a useful resource: On [Regexr](http://regexr.com/) you can fiddle around and validate your regex realltime. (Holy... sorry for that previous link... I thought it was .org o.o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a regular expression such as:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{4}\b
```

The `\b`s ensure that the beginning and end of the four letter pattern `[a-zA-Z]{4}` are word boundaries.

Comment: why did you change from `w` to `[a-zA-z]`? The previous one worked too

Comment: @Sidsec9 `\w` also includes `_`